# Postgres 9.4 Django 1.9 get all json keys

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

I have a JSONField in a django model like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class File(models.Model):
    metadata = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default={})
```

The metadata can be filled with whatever a user likes.

I would like to be able to list all of the unique metadata keys in use by all of the File objects.

Is there a way to do this using django, and postgres, aggregation?

Comment: default should be a callable. More information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483301/django-1-9-jsonfield-update-behavior

Comment: any updates on using jsonb_object_keys from postgres to get Keys ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use Func() expression ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions)) of django to use Postgres function `jsonb_object_keys`([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html))

```
class JsonKeys(Func):
    function = 'jsonb_object_keys'
```

Now you can write

```
File.objects.all().annotate(metadata_keys=JsonKeys('metadata')
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest the following

```
list_of_keys = []
for obj in File.objects.all().values_list('metadata', flat=True)
   list_of_keys = list_of_keys + obj.keys()
```

Now you will have a list of keys, then you can do

```
set = {}
map(set.__setitem__, list_of_keys, [])
unique_keys = set.keys()
```