# Django 1.9 JSONField update behavior

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

I've recently updated to Django 1.9 and tried updating some of my model fields to use the built-in JSONField (I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.5). As I was trying to create and update my object's fields, I came across something peculiar. Here is my model:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    activity_id = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_URL_LENGTH, db_index=True, unique=True)
    my_data = JSONField(default=dict())
```

Here is an example of what I was doing:

```
>>> from proj import models
>>> test, created = models.Activity.objects.get_or_create(activity_id="foo")
>>> created
True
>>> test.my_data['id'] = "foo"
>>> test.save()
>>> test
<Activity: {"id": "foo"}>
>>> test2, created2 = models.Activity.objects.get_or_create(activity_id="bar")
>>> created2
True
>>> test2
<Activity: {"id": "foo"}>
>>> test2.activity_id
'bar'
>>> test.activity_id
'foo'
```

It seems whenever I update any field in `my_data`, the next object I create pre-populates itself with the data from `my_data` from the previous object. This happens whether I use `get_or_create` or just `create`. Can someone explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `default=dict()`. Python dictionaries are mutable. The default dictionary is created once when the models file is loaded. After that, any changes to `instance.my_data` alter the same instance, if they are using the default value.

The solution is to use the callable `dict` as the default instead of `dict()`.

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    my_data = JSONField(default=dict)
```

The [JSONField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) warn about this:

> If you give the field a `default`, ensure it’s a callable such as `dict` (for an empty default) or a callable that returns a `dict` (such as a function). Incorrectly using `default={}` creates a mutable default that is shared between all instances of `JSONField`.

Comment: Wow I thought I had changed it to the callable. Thanks for pointing out that simple mistake!

Answer (score -2):

```
from django_postgres_extensions.models.expressions import Key
obj = Product.objectsannotate(Key('description', 'Details')).get()
obj = Product.objects.annotate(Key('description', 'Details__Rating')).get()
obj = Product.objects.annotate(Key('description', 'Tags__1')).get()

Product.objects.update(description__ = {'Industry': 'Movie', 'Popularity': 'Very Popular'})

Product.objects.update(description__del ='Details')
Product.objects.update(description__del = 'Details__Release')
Product.objects.update(description__del='Tags__1')
```