# Using jsonb_object_keys postgres function in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Is there a way to use `jsonb_object_keys` postgres function in django with the built in ORM ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres 9.4 Django 1.9 get all json keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187721/postgres-9-4-django-1-9-get-all-json-keys)